# Adding custom JS file in wordpress that get apply on any WP theme.

Tags: php, wordpress

I can't work on any specific theme file like header.php, footer.php OR function.php within theme directory.

Reason is project always need new theme and theme is get changes in each week. 
So I want something like that will work on each theme, no matter which theme admin applied.

I tried wp_enqueue_script() but again I need work on theme's function.php file.

Comment: I really do not understand your question. You say, you can not work with function.php, and then you sad, you need work on themes function php. Anyway, write a plugin.

Comment: You need to develop a custom plugin for it.

Comment: Mistake, acetually last sentance should be like- "I tried wp_enqueue_script() but again I do not want to work on theme's function.php file."

Answer (score 2):

The only way to do this is to run wp_enqueue_script() from outside of the theme (i.e. NOT in functions.php). The only way you can do that is to use a plugin.

See: http://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins
Or:  http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin

Create a plugin by adding a .php file in the /wp-content/plugins/ directory, or possibly even better for this situation create a 'must use' plugin by creating a .php file in the /wp-content/mu-plugins/ directory.

The structure of this .php file should be something like the following:

```html
<?php

/*
Plugin Name: Example Plugin
Description: Any functions that should persist even if the theme changes.
Author: Your Name
Version: 1.0
Author URI: http://yoururl.com
*/

function my_scripts() {
  wp_enqueue_script( $handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $in_footer );
}
  
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts' );

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a plugin that rewrites theme's sections. A good start for creating a plugin is [here](https://catn.com/2014/10/06/tutorial-writing-a-simple-wordpress-plugin-from-scratch/). If your themes shares the same Javascript you could try to add your things to those Js.